# Removing duplicates in sql without using aggregate functions

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hashmap, hashset

I'm starting to learn java and I have a problem with my practice exercise.

This is a snippet of the whole code:

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

private static final int MAX_LINES      = 44;

private static final int REPORT_COL1    = 30;   
private static final int REPORT_COL     = 15;   

private ArrayList<String>   errors      = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String>   detailReport    = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String>   summaryReport=  new ArrayList<String>();

String firstSortCode= (String) parameters.get("01");

if(firstSortCode==null || firstSortCode.trim().equals("")) {
    errors.add("Missing required parameter 01");
    invalidParameters= true;
}
else {
    for(int i=0; i<SORT_CODES.length; i++) {
        if(firstSortCode.equals(SORT_CODES[i][0])) {
            pSort1              = SORT_CODES[i][1];
            sort1Attr           = SORT_CODES[i][2];
            sort1GetDescTable   = SORT_CODES[i][3];
            sort1GetDescCode    = SORT_CODES[i][4];
            sort1GetDescValue   = SORT_CODES[i][5];
            val1 = firstSortCode + " - " + pSort1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(pSort1.equals("")) {
        errors.add("Invalid value '"+ firstSortCode + "' for parameter 01");
        invalidParameters= true;
    }
}

String mainSelectSQL ="SELECT shrdgmr_pidm, " +  
"   shrdgmr_levl_code, "+   
"   shrdgmr_grst_code, " 
"  NVL("+sort1Attr+", 'Not Reported') ";


mainSelectSQL =mainSelectSQL +
    "FROM shrdgmr " + 
    "WHERE shrdgmr_pidm is not null " + 

//Appends the ORDER BY clause
mainSelectSQL+= "ORDER BY "+sort1Attr;


//Executes the query and obtains the ResultSet
ResultSet rs= sqlStatement.executeQuery();

String sort1Desc= "***";            
String Sort1Prev= "*";

//Arrays to hold the student counts for each of the reported sort values
int sort1Count= 0;

int grandTotal = 0;

while(rs.next()) {
    String Value1       = rs.getString(2);  

    if(!Value1.equals(prevSort1Value)) {


    String sort1Record= Library.lPad(sort1Count, REPORT_COL, ' ');

    if(!sort1Desc.equals("***")) {

        if(lineCount[0]+4>MAX_LINES) {
            startNewPage(detailReport, pageCount, lineCount, currentDate, 
                databaseName, pGradTerm, pInitiator, sort1Desc, pSort1, false);
        }

            detailReport.add(Library.rPad(sort1Desc, REPORT_COL1, ' ')+sort1Record);
            summaryReport.add(Library.rPad(sort1Desc, REPORT_COL1, ' ')+sort1Record);
            lineCount[0]++;
        }
        //Resets the counter
        sort1Count =0;


        sort1Desc= getSortDescription(connection, pSort1, sort1GetDescValue, sort1GetDescTable,
                                              sort1GetDescCode, Value1, errors);
    }
sort1Count++;
```

My question is how to merge duplicate items and sum up their count?

For example the code I have now just prints the following in my summary report,

Architecture 40
Engineering   56
Dentistry  66
Architecture  16
Computer Science  10
Engineering  11
Architecture 5

the output should only be:

Architecture 61
Engineering   67
Dentistry  66
Computer Science  10
Architecture 5

I'm just stuck on how I can do this. I'm thinking of using hashmap or hashset but I'm not sure how. Any help is appreciatd, thank u!

Comment: Use sql's `group by`

Comment: Your output suggests that you have sets of multiple rows in your source table whose results you want to combine -- a.k.a. *aggregate* -- in the returned results.  This is exactly the purpose of aggregate functions, so why are you trying to avoid the tool specifically designed for problems such as yours?

Comment: Yes, @Andronicus, unless one is trying to avoid aggregate functions, as the OP says they want to do.

Comment: @JohnBollinger right, aggregating without aggregate functions:) what's the point of having them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really dont want to use the aggregate in sql, you can use `HashMap<String, Integer>`. Something like that:

```
Map<String, Integer> aggResult = new HashMap<>();
while (rs.next()) {
    String name = rs.getString(NAME_INDEX); //NAME_INDEX - name column index
    int value = rs.getInt(VALUE_INDEX); //VALUE_INDEX - value column index

    aggResult.merge(name, value, Integer::sum);

    //if you dont have java8 use this "if":
    /*
    if (aggResult.containsKey(name)) {
        Integer sum = aggResult.get(name);
        aggResult.put(name, sum + value);
    } else {
        aggResult.put(name, value);
    }
    */
}
//test output:
aggResult.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + ": " + value));
```

Maybe you will need `TreeMap` (with or without comparator) instead `HashMap` for order, null-checks on values from ResultSet or something else.

Answer (score 0):

There had to be aggregate functions involved and theres no charm in having a query which says "aggregate without aggregate"

With this below query does the needful. I have used sum because your o/p doesnt look actually like a count data but sum of already counted records

```
          SELECT NAME, SUM(*)
           FROM TABLE GROUP BY 
            NAME
```